# Where are the Sharepoint Reporting Services webpart 2010

Tags: web-part, reporting-services

In SP 2007 there was a RS web part -(RS explorer and RS viewer webpart).
And all you need to do is just connect them.
But in SP 2010 i can't seem to find a anything similar.I can only see the Reporting services viewer web part but i need the explorer so that i can  point to specific path.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: how are you creating your reports ?? If you are using SSRS the report configuration lets you set the path. target and other properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They exist as part of the SQL Server installation.  We've put the 2010 report server web parts into our newly built 2010 farm.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159772.aspx